# RxJS distinctUntilChanged is emits same values multiple times

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Can you guys tell me what is wrong here.

**RxJS**

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eqffs/1064/)

I was expecting the value will print only one time,but it is printing mulitple times

[image: JsFiddle]

```
function Search(sel) {
    let observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('iCard'), 'input');
    observable
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe({
        next: this.callGlobalSearch
      });
  }

  function callGlobalSearch(e){
    console.log('VALUE : ', e.target.value); // NOT SURE, WHY THE VALUE IS PRINTED MULTIPLE TIMES
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed your code in fiddle [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2heokyn/). You don't need to subscribe to `input` event on every `keyup`. And `distinctUntilChanged` was getting event object which is different always. So it can't do anything. Before that event should be mapped to text, then it can be compared in `distinctUntilChanged`.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('iCard'), 'input')
  .debounceTime(1000)
  .map(e => e.target.value)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe({
    next: callGlobalSearch
  });

function callGlobalSearch(text) {
  console.log('VALUE : ', text);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ... distinctUntilChanged equality check happens on the event object, which is a new instance every time. Putting a map on e.target.value will do the equality comparison on the string value, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you `keyup` you run the function `Search(sel)`.

Any time you run the function `Search(sel)` you create an Observable and you subscribe to it.

So after **n** `keyup` events you end up having **n** active subscriptions to **n** different source Observables, and therefore you see **n** repetitions of the line logged on the console.

If change the html code such as

```
<body onload="Search(this)"> 

Global Search
<input id="iCard" type='text' />

</body>body>
```

you should get the right behavior.
Change the name of the function `Search` to something more aligned to the real stuff performed, e.g. `createInputObs`, according to your style.

Comment: Ho, you corrected me,  Can you please tell me then what event I should use instead of keyup